# SliverFillRemaining doesn't allow pull to refresh-indicator work. How to fix this?

Tags: flutter

I am using a package `incrementally_loading_listview` to paginate my data from firestore. And I am using it inside a `custom-scroll-view`. Problem is I had to wrap it inside `SliverFillRemaining` widget to display my data. And as a result, the `refresh-indicator` is not working now. I am using slivers because I will have sliver-grid also.

Earlier I was using `SliverListBuilderDelegate` to dynamically load my data using `scroll-controller`. Problem with that was whenever I reach the top of my list, it calls `_getMoreProducts`(which I don't want, I want to load data only when I reach the bottom), which results in snappy scrolling(it snaps if I again scroll down instantly). `Refresh-indicator` works with this solution. I will use this method if SliverFillRemaining doesn't work.

This is my `SliverFillRemaining` code. `refresh-indicator` doesn't work.

```dart
      Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFAF5F2),
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _refresh,
          child: CustomScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverFillRemaining(
          child: IncrementallyLoadingListView(
            hasMore: () => _moreProductsAvailable,
            itemCount: () => _products.length,
            loadMore: () async {
              await _getMoreProducts();
            },
            loadMoreOffsetFromBottom: 2,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Post.fromDocument(_products[index]);
                },
               ),
             ) 
            ],
          ),
        ));
```

And this was my earlier code with `SliverListBuilder`. This calls `_getMoreProducts` everytime I scroll top.

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   _getProducts();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
      double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
      double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25;

      if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= delta) {
        _getMoreProducts();
      }
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
        body: RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: _refresh,
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
         SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, 
           index) {
            return Dismissible(
                key: ObjectKey(_products[index]),
                background: Container(color: Colors.red),
                onDismissed: (direction) {
                  var item = _products.elementAt(index);
                  setState(() {
                    _products.removeAt(index);
                  });
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(
                      content: Text("product removed"),
                      action: SnackBarAction(
                        label: "UNDO",
                        onPressed: (){
                          setState(() {
                            _products.insert(index, item);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Product.fromDocument(_products[index]));
          }, childCount: _products.length),
        )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

So, I want a sliver-widget which can paginate as well as can do refresh with the refresh indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved my problem by adding the `refresh-indicator` to the child of `SliverFillRemaining`.

```dart
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFAF5F2),
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: CustomScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            slivers: <Widget>[
             SliverFillRemaining(
          child: RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: _refresh,
            child: IncrementallyLoadingListView(
              hasMore: () => _moreProductsAvailable,
              itemCount: () => _products.length,
              loadMore: () async {
                await _getMoreProducts();
              },
              loadMoreOffsetFromBottom: 2,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Product.fromDocument(_products[index]);
              },
            ),
          ),
        )
            ],

        ));
```